# Complexification linear algebraic group.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ and $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ denote, respectively, the algebraic groups of real and complex isomorphisms. I know that $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ can be seen as a subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ but, can it be regarded as a complex algebraic subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$? I think that the answer is no...

As $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ is obtained through base extension from $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ I know that I have a morphism $GL(n, \mathbb{C}) \to GL(n, \mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 2):

1. No. One way to see this is that a complex algebraic subgroup necessarily has a Lie algebra which is a complex Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$, but the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is not closed under scalar multiplication by complex numbers.
2. There is no such surjective morphism.

Comment: What I was thinking is that I can naturally identify $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ with a subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ using that $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ is the complexification of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. So the question is, is this subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ an algebraic subgroup?

Comment: In terms of Lie algebras this means that $\mathfrak{g}\mathfrak{l}(n, \mathbb{C})$ has real Lie subalgebra which is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}\mathfrak{l}(n, \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @gal16: yes, I understand the question. The answer is no, because $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is not a *complex* Lie subalgebra.